# Abas em session?

Tags: bug, status-intencional

Reparei que quando se clica em uma aba e volta para as questões recentes escolhendo no menu Tag, ela sempre abra a ultima aba...

1. Aba Recentes - https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php
2. Aba Destaque - https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php?sort=featured&pageSize=50
3. Menu Tags + PHP - https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tags

Depois do 3º passo entra o link da principal que deveria ser a *aba recentes* referente ao link: `https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php`, mas a aba marcada é *aba destaque*.

Não importa qual a aba e qual a Tag, sempre ativa a ultima aba clicada.

Comment: Relacionado com o que escrevi aqui: http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/a/1524/227